# Azure Deployment Timeout: "Post Run actions/checkout@v3" Step Hangs Indefinitely

Tags: angular, azure, github, github-actions

I'm deploying an Angular app to Azure Static Web Apps using GitHub Actions. The build process completes without errors, but the workflow hangs on the "Post Run actions/checkout@v3" step until it eventually times out and the deployment is aborted. This issue is preventing my app from being deployed successfully.

Below is a snapshot of my GitHub workflow file build process:

[Azure Build & Deploy Workflow-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2svNa.png)
[image]

[Azure Build & Deploy Workflow-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6uSB.png)
[image]

Comment: Can you please share the GitHub Repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is solved now, the problem was neither with the app nor the Azure Static Apps configuration, rather it was due to autostart functionality of the custom-webpack-bundle analyser added to the app which prompted opening the browser during the production build, which Azure couldn't do; hence it got hang & the process ran indefinitely.

New webpack.config.js code:

```js
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const plugins = [];

if (process.env.ANALYZE) {
  plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin());
}

module.exports = { plugins };
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to deploy an Angular app to Azure Static Web Apps using GitHub Actions.

Create a GitHub repository.

This is my **.yml file**

```yaml
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
          lfs: false
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_ASHY_DESERT_SECRET_KEY }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          action: "upload" 
          app_location: "/" 
          api_location: "" 
          output_location: "dist/angular-basic" 
  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_ASHY_DESERT_SECRET_KEY }}
          action: "close"
```

After creating the repository in your GitHub account, use the command below to copy the project to your local machine.

```html
git clone https://github.com/<YOUR_GITHUB_ACCOUNT_NAME>static-web-app.git
```

Then, open Visual Studio Code and go to File > Open Folder to open the copied repository in the editor.

**Install Azure static webapps extension:**

1. Select View > Extension.
2. In the Search Extensions in Marketplace, type Azure Static Web Apps.
3. Select Install for Azure Static Web Apps.
4. The extension installs into Visual Studio Code.

**Create a Static web app**

In Visual Studio code, select the Azure logo in the taskbar to open the Azure window.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

1.Once the app is created, a confirmation notification is shown in Visual Studio Code.

2. Once the deployment is complete, you can navigate directly to your website.

[image]

4. To view the website in the browser, right-click the project in the Static Web Apps extension and select **Browse Site**.

[image]

Here's the Output:

[image]